# Error creating click event in shopping cart Angular + primeNg

Tags: angular, clique

When creating the click event in the shopping cart, it gives an error when inserting the function parameter: "onDelete(cartItem)"
I don't understand why the problem. can you help me? Thanks!

CART-COMPONENT.HTML

```
<button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Remove"class="p-button-danger (click)="onDelete(cartItem)" p-button-text" ></button>
```

CART-COMPONENT.TS

```
  onDelete(cartItem: CartItem) {
    this.cartService.remove(cartItem);
  }
```

CART.SERVICE

````
  remove(cartItem: CartItem) {
    const itemIndex = this.cartItems.findIndex(tempCartItem => tempCartItem.id === cartItem.id);

    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      this.cartItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      this.computeCartTotals();
    }
  }```




I tried to remove the parameter but the error persists.
````

Comment: What error? Please be specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the error is: The cartItem parameter is underlined in red in the html page and it says: "The property 'cartItem' does not exist in the type 'CartDetailsComponent'. Did you mean 'cartItems'?ngtsc(2551)"

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not giving us the exact error, or even whether you are getting a compile or runtime error, I can only guess:

In your template example, there are multiple syntax errors. Your double-quote characters are in all the wrong places. So this would explain compile errors. A correct version of the template might look like this:

```html
<button pButton pRipple type="button" 
        label="Remove" class="p-button-danger" 
        (click)="onDelete(cartItem)"
        p-button-text></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the error is as follows. The cartItem parameter is underlined in red and reads: "The 'cartItem' property does not exist on type 'CartDetailsComponent'. Did you mean 'cartItems'?ngtsc(2551)"